# Can you recommend a PostgreSQL Visual Database Designer for Linux?

Tags: linux, database-design, postgresql, olap

When I'm in Windows, I use the **excellent** [MicroOLAP](http://www.microolap.com/products/database/postgresql-designer/) Database Designer for PostgreSQL, but its not open source or multiplataform.
Do you know or can recommend me an alternative to this software, that I can use in Linux?

*EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't want to use wine to emulate MicroOlap for PostgreSQL, it doesn't work too well, I would prefer something native, or Java based.*

Comment: Maybe, limit products to open-source only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[pgDesigner](http://pgdesigner.sourceforge.net/) is a database design application for PostgreSQL, for
 versions 7.x and 8.x.

pgDesigner provides the following features:

- Complete datamodel editor
- Support for PostgreSQL objects: tables, views, relations,
  tablespaces, procedures, triggers, types, domains and sequences
- Automatic updating of relations between tables.
- Wizard for the construction of views.
- Report generator, with statistics
- Printing the diagram
- SQL export
- Creation of the database
- Management of the project on a diagram chart

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using software database designers years ago, and reverted back to the trusty pen and paper which is just easier to use in my experience.

To answer your question though, take a look at [dbDesigner4](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) which is what I used to use. I remember it being fantastic. It's open source and multiplatform.

Comment: dbDesigner4 looks like it's designed for MySQL, while @OP is looking for a designer for PostgreSQL.

Comment: That's right, dbDesigner4 is for MySQL, in fact, is the base for **MySQL Workbench**, but thanks for answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Clay](http://www.azzurri.jp/en/clay/index.html)? It's a plugin for Eclipse, and the free version supports generating Postgres DDL.

Answer (score 0):

I really like dbWrench.  It's commercial as well, but not expensive and is Java based.  It can reverse engineer a database and generates pretty good HTML based documentation.

http://www.dbwrench.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is a crappy answer for which I should be taken out and shot, but you can search over nearly all PostgreSQL related projects at [PgFoundry](http://pgfoundry.org/).  I don't know from GUI database design tools, but I'd imagine you should be able to find something there, if it exists.